# App_Data directory not published with Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a few fonts and a PDF file in the App_Data directory of my Web API project which is published to an Azure Mobile Service.

The build action is set to Content and I can see in the output window that the files are being published but when my code runs it cannot find the directory anywhere.

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Yields

```
"D:\\local\\Temporary ASP.NET Files\\root\\aea53938\\87de4b2f\\assembly\\dl3\\fb538bd2\\f38b146c_6ea3d001\\
```

Both of these

```
HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath
HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/")
```

Yield

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SiteExtensions\\MobileServicesDotNet\\1.0.450\\
```

If I do a Directory.GetFiles() and Directory.GetDirectories() using the directories above, none of them show an App_Data folder.

Where is this mystery folder located? Several Stackoverflow posts have suggested looking in bin\App_Data but it's not there either.

Comment: @astaykov Any chance I could get your help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that in VS Publish --> Settings the exclude option for App_Data is not set.